# Configuring groovy SDK within Intellij: have to repeat this each time project is built?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, sdk

I was getting an error when trying to compile my application within `Intellij`:

> Error:Cannot compile Groovy files: no Groovy library is defined for module

I solved this issue by selecting `"Configure Groovy SDK"` for the module, when prompted by Inteli. I used library `org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.4` , this then adds this library as a `dependency` for the module.

The issue is that each time I *re-build* my project or *"refresh gradle projects"* in Intellij I have to "Configure Groovy SDK" again.

How can I set up my project so that I *don't have to re-do* this step each time?

Comment: Is the dependency added to your build.gradle?

Comment: It is added at the project level (top level) but not in that modules build.gradle? Should I add it there?

Comment: I guess it's worth a try.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

add groovy-all as a dependency to in your pom.xml (if you're using maven) or your build.gradle (for gradle). Otherwise every time your refresh or sync, intellij will remove the "extra" dependency it finds.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you paste an example?

Comment: @MarkHu I've edited it for you. In the future, you can go to http://search.maven.org/ and look for the dependency (in this case "groovy-all"). Click on the version you want, and there will be a small xml snippet on the left-hand side that you can copy-paste (http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.codehaus.groovy%7Cgroovy-all%7C2.4.7%7Cjar)